# Custom taxonomy category images

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

I have used the types plugin and added a custom taxonomy. Under the Taxonomy i have created 3 categories. Now my question is that how can i attach a image to those categories. If you think about any plugins, I have used taxonomy Images and others. Those plugins have added the image to default category. But not to the custom taxonomy categories.

Comment: can you please share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement for my site and I gone through this from Bainternet.info and got it working charmly

[Here is the repo from github](https://github.com/bainternet/Tax-Meta-Class)

Comment: Small heads up: As of WordPress 4.4.1, this isn't working anymore.  More details here: https://github.com/bainternet/Tax-Meta-Class/issues/117

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin to add a custom field (an image field) to you custom taxonomy group or individual taxonomies.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use plugin, then I think this is best up to now:

[Wordpress Plugin :: Categories Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/)

This plugin supports any types of custom taxonomy and uses WP media gallery; It's quick edit feature is very nice;

```
//The image size can be: thumbnail|medium|large|full|array(20,30), etc.
echo '<img src"'.z_taxonomy_image_url($term_id, 'thumbnail').'" alt="" >';
```

To know more about it visit here: [Documentation](http://zahlan.net/blog/2012/06/categories-images/)